# pugixml - how to get the document from a contained node

Tags: c++, pugixml

I was wondering it there is a way to obtain the xml_document that contains a given xml_node. Looking at the API doc xml_node provides the method root() but the return type is xml_node instead of xml_document. Is there a way to work around this in order to get the document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is your friend.

Comment: I'm not sure about using dynamic_cast here. Have you seen the implementation of xml_document::document_element()? It performs the opposite, it returns a xml_node representing the document, and it doesn't return just "this" so I suppose a downcast here would be wrong.

Comment: No but I'm sure it has a way to get the parent node. So when you get root, you get it's parent, do a `dynamic_cast`. If it's not NULL Ta da!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to get the parent node using xml_node::parent(), which is going to give you a new xml_node object which wraps (points to) the internal structure of the node (xml_node_struct). There is no way you can downcast to xml_document here.

Comment: This is not possible right now - the root().internal_object() pointer refers to xml_document_struct that is contained within xml_document but it's not possible to get a pointer to the xml_document object itself. Usually I recommend to just keep track of the document in the user code - what is your use case?

Comment: I need to take nodes out of the document and put them back if the action gets reverted. Because of performance, I am interested in moving nodes rather than copying them. I have a series of interfaces that hide the underlying XLM implementation I'm using (pugixml in this case). They idea is to implement DocumentFragments. Internally, I have a separate node for storing fragments. The creation of fragments is provided by the Document interface, which should be accessible from any Node: Node.ownerDocument attribute according to DOM Level 1. This way I wouldn't need to keep track of the document.

Comment: This does not look like it requires xml_document though. The only operations exclusive to xml_document type are load/save related - so for your case it should be enough to get access to the special node using node.root().child("storage") or equivalent code.